# Does "nessuno" translate to "no one" or "anyone"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, pronouns

I found that the sentence *"Loro non hanno assunto nessuno"* translates to *"They did not hire anyone"*.

Since *nessuno* begins with "n-", I would think it translates to "no one", but the English word in this case is "anyone". Is there a separate word for "anyone"? Why is "nessuno" used here? This seems like a double negative to me - are those common in Italian?

Comment: Well, maybe my problem is that I don't understand the difference of usage between "no one" and "anyone" because I would translate this sentence as "They hired no one".

Comment: You use "non" with "nessuno" when "nessuno" is written after the verb. For instance, "Qui non c'è nessuno" but "Nessuno ha parlato".

Comment: Both. It depends on the context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, double negatives are grammatical, and common, in Italian.

See on this monolingual [dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nessuno/), for instance:

> Se posposto al verbo, è di solito rafforzato da altra negazione (non, né, senza, ecc.).

My translation: when the word nessuno comes after the verb, usually it is reinforced by another negation: non, né, senza, etc.

Examples from the same source:

> non c’era quasi nessuno; nessuno ha potuto vedermi; non mi ha visto nessuno

You could say *non hanno assunto alcuna persona* instead, which would be the literal translation (any = alcuno), but it is used a lot less.

Also, a historical note from the [same source](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/nessuno-o-alcuno_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)

> L’uso di nessuno insieme a un’altra negazione non era ammesso nel latino classico, ma trova ampi riscontri nel latino tardo ed era perfettamente accettabile già nell’italiano antico
>
> *già non è nessuno / cui non posse di botto / dicere* (B. Latini, Il tesoretto).

Comment: I'd say that *anyone* translates more accurately as *chiunque*. The problem is that in Italian double negatives are essentially mandatory, and so giving a word-for-word translation of a sentence is problematic.